# Save and get the Chinese character data in android, json, php and mysql.

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am adding some book information with Chinese character to `MySQL` through android application in `wamp` environment,and I found that the Chinese character cannot display correctly,it will display as `?????` in `phpmyadmin`. This problem makes my application cannot search the book with Chinese name.
 Although I have search a lot of similar problem,but the provided method still cannot solve the problem.
 Can somebody tell me how to solve this problem steps by step so i can solve it easily and find out which part is missed ?

**Note:** Myphp version is 5.3.13

Comment: in mysql, how r u saving data ? means have u made 'Collation' type of that filed?

Comment: collation is using utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

You should choose proper charset:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

About how character are seen on phpmyadmin is caused by your browser, try changing it's encoding value in your preferences